# What does Redis do when setting a key with both EX and KEEPTTL options specified?

Tags: redis

It's not clear to me in the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/set) what happens with a `SET` command if you use both the `EX` and `KEEPTTL` options.

In my mind, there are three options:

1. If the key exists, does not modify TTL. If the key does not exist
   uses the expiry specified with `EX` option
2. If the key exists, does not modify TTL. If the key does not
   exist, it does not set an expiry and the entry lives forever
3. ignores `KEEPTTL` and sets the expiry on new and existing keys

Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

Instead, Redis returns an error reply, since these two options are conflict.

Comment: You also get an error if you throw a `NX` into the mix. Just tested with CLI.